# register app to read e-mail attachments

Tags: android, email, attachment

I want to send a file, created in the app and send it to another user.
This user should be able to open the attachment with the app and use my sent file for his work. Mime-type is : java-serialized-object : .ser

My Manifest

```
<application
           <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/*"
                android:host="*" 
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.ser"
            /> 
        </intent-filter>
```

My View, containing the emailIntent:

```
Intent emailIntent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
 emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Pentacubes BETA-TEST");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, report);

 filename = "level_0_2_0.ser" ;
 File myFile = new File("/sdcard/" + filename); 
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
 emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
emailIntent.setType("application/java-serialized-object");
```

sending email is o.k. 
If I open the email in the email program, containing the .ser in the attachment, my app is not registered to read the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of android:pathPattern probably blocks receiving gmail intents since in intent's URI there can be no extension, even if displayed in gmail UI. In order to check if you can receive any intents from gmail, check out this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="*" android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

In that way you will be able to debug your application and find out what mime type is given for desired attachments.

If you want to filter received intents by extension, you can still do it programmatically.